# ¿Como validar los campos de la base de datos?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quiero saber como validar cuando un numero que se inserta desde la aplicacion es mayor al valor que tengo en la base de datos para que no sea menos que cero o cuando el valor es igual a cero, estoy programando en tres capas,  este es mi codigo;

**negocio

```
public DataTable Comcantidad(String SKU)
     {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String query = "SELECT Cantidad FROM almacen WHERE SKU = '" + SKU + "'";
        dt = daccess.select(query);
        return dt;
     }
```

**vista

```
DataTable num = biss.Comcantidad(txt_sku.Text);
        Double cant = Double.Parse(num.Rows[0]["Cantidad"].ToString());
        if (cant == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pueden hacer salidas porque la cantidad del prodeucto es 0");
            this.txt_sku.Clear();
            this.txt_status.Clear();
            this.txt_descripcion.Clear();
            this.txt_unidad.Clear();
            this.txt_costo.Clear();
            this.txt_cantidad.Clear();
            this.txt_proveedor.Clear();
            this.txt_familia.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable Obtenerid = biss.MllenartxtDesc(txt_descripcion.Text);
            int ids = Int32.Parse(Obtenerid.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString());
            int idu = Int32.Parse(Obtenerid.Rows[0]["Unidad"].ToString());
            int idp = Int32.Parse(Obtenerid.Rows[0]["Proveedor"].ToString());
            int idf = Int32.Parse(Obtenerid.Rows[0]["Familia"].ToString());

            biss.Gsalidas(txt_sku.Text, ids, txt_descripcion.Text, idu, Convert.ToDouble(txt_cantidad.Text), idp, idf, Convert.ToDouble(txt_costo.Text));

            biss.Aalmacenmenos(txt_sku.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txt_cantidad.Text));

            Close();
        }
```

Comment: no entiendo la pregunta. la validacion esta ya en el codigo que pasas... cual es el problema?

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que quieres hacer, si necesitas saber el numero mayor que ya tienes seria algo tan simple como un [MAX en Sql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_max), aunque personalmente preferiría usar [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Podrías consultarlo y solo comparar con el que estas tratando de ingresar.

Comment: Un buen curso de c#, un buen libro o incluso hasta google te ayudaría bastante ;)